# Search other Drives in windows for certain files in Python 3

Tags: windows-7, python-3.3, cd-rom

I'm creating a Python 3 program for Windows 7 to search for common names for installation executables on a CD and run it. I have tried using multiple os.path.exists but when it finds the correct file, it prints that it can't find the other possible file names.
Please help!

```
        if os.path.exists("D:/autorun.exe"):
            os.startfile("D:/autorun.exe")
        else:
            print("Failed Attempt!")
        if os.path.exists("D:/Install.exe"):
            os.startfile("D:/Install.exe")
        else:
            print("Failed Attempt!")
        if os.path.exists("D:/AutoRun.exe"):
            os.startfile("D:/AutoRun.exe")
        else:
            print("Failed Attempt!")
        if os.path.exists("D:/install.exe"):
            os.startfile("D:/install.exe")
        else:
            print("Failed Attempt!")
```

Comment: I really don't know what to do!

Comment: added the code in question!

Comment: Could you show me an example of how this is used?

Comment: This is not very helpful because it is used the same as os.path.exists! I need something that will check a bunch of possible filenames and return "Can't find install.exe" ect. if all of them fail.

Comment: Sorry. What I meant was if I did my code in the GUI i'm using it would pop up as Failed Attempt until in found the right file. I wan't it just to do that once if it doesn't find ANY possible file names. It really wasn't an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you code appears to appears to be at the same indent level, each one of your `if`/`else` blocks will be executed one after another, therefore printing "Failed Attempt!" for each filepath that does not exist. Given your comment on March 12, you could use a `for` loop followed by a `if`/`else` block to ensure that "Failed Attempt!" is printed only once all files had been checked for existance. See the code below (NOTE: As I don't have Windows 7 handy, I have not tested this, but it should work):

```
import os
FILES = ('D:/autorun.exe', 'D:/Install.exe', 'D:/AutoRun.exe', 'D:/install.exe')
FILE_FOUND = False

for file in FILES:
    if os.path.exists(file):
        FILE_FOUND = file
        break

if FILE_FOUND:
    os.startfile(FILE_FOUND)
else:
    print("Failed Attempt!")
```

So to break it down step-by-step:

1. Import the `os` module, which you have obviously done this elsewhere already.
2. The filepaths for each file to be checked are to be stored as a tuple in `FILES`. A tuple is used because it is 'immutable' and therefore we know it will be stored exactly as shown above. This is also handy as it will mean that the for loop will check each file in the order from left to right.
3. `FILE_FOUND` is initially assigned as `False`. This will be used later for 2 things:

   - To store the filepath string of a file from `FILES`, if it exists.
   - To be use to determine if `os.startfile()` should be executed.
4. Next is the `for` loop. Each filepath string in the `FILES` tuple will be made available to be checked by the indented code following `for file in FILES:`. The `file` variable is a string representing the current filepath from `FILES`, and it is local to the code associated with the `for` loop.  The loop then checks if a file exists at the given filepath string in `file`. If it the file exists, `FILE_FOUND` is assigned the string stored in `file`. The `break` statement then exits the `for` loop without any regard for any items in `FILES` that haven't been checked. Otherwise, the `for` loop will continue to run until it runs out of items to check in `FILES`.
5. Finally, the `if`/`else` code block will only run once the `for` loop has either found a file that exists, or has finished working through all items in `FILES`. If `FILE_FOUND` evaluates as `True` (by virtue of not being `None`, `0`, `False`, or as per the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#booleans)), `os.startfile(FILE_FOUND)` will be executed, where we know that the filepath string of the existing file had been previously stored in `FILE_FOUND` by the `for` loop. If none of the filepath strings were found to exist in the `for` loop, the `FILE_FOUND` variable will still be `False`, therefore printing "Failed Attempt!".

Comment: I am using Linux now...  so how would I do this? The cds automatically get mounted in the /media directory but this is going to be general, so how do I do this by just searching for filenames (instead of path and filenames)?